# from wide to long with R pivot_longer() with two within-factors stored in one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyverse, reshape

I want to compute an ANOVA with two within-subject factors for which I first need to transform the file format from wide to long. The variable-name here includes 2 different within-factors: the 3-factor variable lureType (new, sem, per) and the 2-factor variable emotion (Neu, Neg) its value represents the dependent variable (falseAlarms).

So, I start with selecting the relevant variables:

```
long_file <- wide_file %>%
  select(ID, betweenVariable, newNeu_falseAlarm,newNeg_falseAlarm,
semNeu_falseAlarm,semNeg_falseAlarm,
perNeu_falseAlarm,perNeg_falseAlarm) %>%
```

If the variable would only include one within factor, I would follow with this
for emotion:

```
 pivot_longer(cols = c(Neg_falseAlarm, Neu_falseAlarm),
               names_to = "emotion",
               values_to = "falseAlarms")
```

or for lureType:

```
pivot_longer(cols = c(new_falseAlarm, sem_falseAlarm, per_falseAlarm),
               names_to = "lureType",
               values_to = "falseAlarms")
```

Does anyone know how to transform a long format into a wide format if the variable stores two different factors?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
pivot_longer(cols=c(newNeu_falseAlarm,newNeg_falseAlarm, semNeu_falseAlarmsemNeg_falseAlarm perNeu_falseAlarm,perNeg_falseAlarm),
               names_to=c("lureType","emotion"),
               names_sep= "N",
               values_to = "falseAlarms"
               )
```

Happy, if anyone wants to add a more elegant solution. I'm not too familiar with R.